# How to enable date and time picker in Bootstrap-DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using this [Bootstrap-DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) with the latest version of 4.17.47.

I read all the documentation options, functions, and events.

I also included all dependencies of JS and CSS.

But something is not working properly somehow.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm',
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

There is an option of **format** in the documentation about displaying calendar part or time-picker part.

What I want is to display both parts i.e. calendar and time-picker.

But when I set `format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'` it shows the calendar part properly.

When I set `format: 'hh:mm'` it shows time-picker properly.

But when I set `format:'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'` to enable both parts, it doesn't show calendar part and only show icon for time-picker and when I click that icon it opens time-picker. This is the same case if I do not set **format** option explicitly and keep it default to **false**.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you get some error from the console? I've tried with your code and I see it work  correctly [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zjwtehn/)

Comment: @nmbrphi No, there is no console error. I think you are using an older version of bootstrap and date-time-picker both. Your bootstrap.min,js is of version-3 ,while I am using the version-4.

Comment: that's probably the problem, this library was developed for bootstrap 3 and I did't see any support or change for bootstrap 4. [github project](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently Bootstrap-DateTimePicker [does not support Bootstrap 4](https://github.com/UdashFramework/udash-core/issues/205).
In fact, your code looks fine with Bootstrap 3.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm',
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```